# Throwing Checked Exception vs Throwing a wrapped RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

At many places, I get several Checked Exceptions like IOException, ParseException, JSONException, etc. I had to make either of 2 choices -

1. Throw the same exception by adding throws at the end of method signature.
2. Wrap the checked Exception in a RuntimeException(or some custom implementation) and then throw it so that caller doesn't have to add throws clause everywhere and check the exceptions.

In the first case, I will have to put throws everywhere, but my client can decide not to die by catching the checkedException and continuing to work. In 2nd case, however the RuntimeException may actually force the client to fail, as generally people don't catch Generic/RuntimeExceptions everywhere. Also using 2nd approach makes it easier to use Java 8 lambdas which doesn't work well with Checked Exceptions.

Which one of the two is preferred over another and why? Is there any preferred practice to follow?

Comment: I don't think there is a *right* answer, but if you look at the Spring Framework, the trend is to wrap the checked exceptions under a runtime exception.  Document either through JavaDoc or the throws clause what could be called so if clients want to handle it they can.

Comment: @wero that is very bad practice, since it will include exceptions that you aren't currently throwing, but would if your implementation changes, and should be handled in specific ways. The obvious example is InterruptedException.

Comment: @wero why do you consider me a hypocrite? Do you simply mean that you disagree? I'm no hypocrite (on this, at least): I practice what I advocate.

Comment: @wero Of course there are situations where it is useful to throw `Exception`: for instance, in the `Callable` interface, where *any* code can be executed, *any* exception *could* be thrown. This is what `throws Exception` says: prepare for *anything*. Using it in code which can only throw specific exceptions because you don't want to expend a few more keystrokes which tell your callers exactly what problems they might encounter is plain laziness, and massively increases burden on the caller by removing bounds on the problems they might encounter; ...

Comment: @wero ...further, the types of problems they might encounter can change without any indication that their handling code needs to change: that is what I call a very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of exceptions: exceptions that can be expected for a call and exceptions that are in principle unexpected (and that the application code probably cannot work around in a meaningful way). For the first kind (e.g. IOException for a file operation), checked exceptions (with 'throws' at the end of a method signature) are great.

For the second situation, it is my opinion that it's fine to wrap it in a RuntimeException for the reasons that you state (not having to add throws everywhere). All software should be prepared to catch RuntimeExceptions at the top level as a 'last line of defense', or they accept that a RuntimeException will end the program (which is often acceptable for instance for command line applications).

An example for the second situation is that a necessary configuration file is missing. I would rethrow that IOException as a RuntimeException.

By the way, there is a third way that is often used: throwing an application-specific exception. For instance this exception could be called 'MyConfigurationException'. I think this is only useful if an application can catch this exception and handle it intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Throw the same checked exception by adding throws at the end of method signature:**

> Use this if the caller can recover from the exception or at least has
>   to take some decision/progress based upon that

**(2) Wrap the checked Exception in a RuntimeException(or some custom implementation):**

> Use this if the caller can't recover (Most of the Exceptions in
>   Spring/Hibernate frameworks follow this pattern)

Answer (score 0):

There is a third option, which is to throw the same checked Exception but to 'soften' it. CheckedExceptions are enforced only at Compile time, and by casting your Exception to a Throwable, you can safely throw it without the compiler complaining. Here is an example implementation (available in [cyclops-functions](https://github.com/aol/cyclops/tree/master/cyclops-functions) a library I contribute to - or you can copy and paste :) )

**UPDATE** Simplified ExceptionSoftener class as per Andy Turner's comment.

```
public class ExceptionSoftener {


   public static <T extends Throwable> T softenedException(final T e) {
       uncheck(e);
       return e; //never reached.
   }

   private static <T extends Throwable> void uncheck(Throwable throwable) throws T {
       throw (T) throwable;

   }

 }

   public void methodThrowsIOException(){      
       throw ExceptionSoftener.softenedException(new IOException("checked exception, but no declaration required!"));
   }
```

Comment: Is the `Thrower` class necessary here: why not just declare `private static <T extends Throwable> void uncheck(Throwable t) throws T` inside `ExceptionSoftener`, and invoke `ExceptionSoftener.<RuntimeException>uncheck(e)`?

Comment: I'd have thought it would be a good idea to make the return type of `throwSoftenedException` `RuntimeException` instead of `void`, in order that you can use `throw ExceptionSoftener.throwSoftenedException(...)` to indicate to the compiler that execution will stop on that line.

Comment: Is this what you mean? - public static <T extends Throwable,R> R throwSoftenedException(final T e); It has to be a new type rather than T if what we are trying to do is allow code like :- return throwSoftenedException(new IOException()); which will stop the compiler complaining that a method doesn't return something (when in fact an exception is thrown). That would work too. I'll add another method with that option. It's definitely moving further into the realms of tricking the compiler for sure :)

Comment: Why can't R simply be `RuntimeException`? Incidentally, this is exactly what Guava's [Throwables.propagate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#propagate(java.lang.Throwable)) does.

Comment: Although it is compiler trickery, I would argue that `throw` is better than `returns`, because it indicates clearly that an exception is thrown at that line, rather than returning some arbitrary value. I refer again to the Guava Throwables javadoc. And, having a Throwable as the return type removes the need for the two methods.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I didn't think of throws throwSoftenedException(checkedException). That is better. Another update :) Btw, do you want to submit a Pull Request?